# Why does array change in non manipulated component in Angular2?

Tags: arrays, angular, service, components

I am following the Angular tutorial on angular.io (http://angular.io/tutorial/) and I was trying the alter an array filled with 'heroes'. I found a shuffle function which randomises my array, however once I use this function, my local(?) heroes array should be randomised but it seems to randomise my overall heroes array in both components.

Can anyone explain what is happening and how I can randomise the array in one component without changing the array and keeping the same order in the other component?

I put the code on Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/4ldD1pvoAPsY12MOeznP?p=preview
(somehow I can't get it to run though, works fine on my computer) (*link is updated)

Thanks!

Service:

```
export class HeroService {
  getHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]> {
    return Promise.resolve(HEROES);
  }
```

Component 1:

```
  heroes: Hero[] = [];

  constructor(private heroService: HeroService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.heroService.getHeroes()
      .then((heroes) => {
        this.heroes = this.shuffle(heroes).slice(1,5) });

  }

  shuffle(array:Array<any>){
    var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;
    // While there remain elements to shuffle...
    while (0 !== currentIndex) {

      // Pick a remaining element...
      randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
      currentIndex -= 1;

      // And swap it with the current element.
      temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
      array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
      array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
    }

    return array;
  }
}
```

Component 2:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getHeroes();
  }

  getHeroes(): void {
    this.heroService.getHeroes().then(heroes => this.heroes = heroes;
  }
```

Comment: Hi, not clear without the full code. Try holding the the heroes in a variable (ie localHeroes) and pass that to the shuffle  function.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I did try that but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: Try creating a new instance of heroes( why I assume is an array of objects) this.heroService.getHeroes()
      .then((heroes) => {
        let localHeroes : Hero[] = [];
        localHeroes = heroes.map(hero => {
            return new Hero(hero);
        });

        this.heroes = this.shuffle(localHeroes).slice(1,5) });

  }

Comment: I'm getting the following error message:
Supplied parameters do not match any signarture of call target.
I get this for the 'return new Hero(hero);'

Comment: Try this.  return new hero;

Comment: Your plunker is not the same as the question

Comment: What do you mean? My plunker has more elaborate code compared to the question.

Comment: No, check the plunker link again, might have added the wrong link.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I am updating the plunker right now :)